# For x in range(y) não retorna certo

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou com um problema em um def x() em python. o Problema é "dentro" dele.
Mesmo que eu coloque certo, ele retorna o else, não importa.

Já tentei de tudo mas não consegui saber porque ele não retorna certo.

Aqui vai o código.

```
def filters(a, b, c):
    for a in range(1, 1):
    d = "video"
    else:
    d = ""

    for b in range(1, 1):
    e = "&lclk=short"
    else:
    e = ""

    for c in range(1, 1):
    f = "&lclk=hd"
    else:
    f = ""

    i = ("&filters=%s%s%s" % (e, d, f))
    return i
```

Mesmo que eu coloque filters(1, 1, 1) ele retorna só os "elses". Por que será? Ah detalhe que se eu tentar por if dentro do def ele fala "syntax error" :/ ( é python 2.7 )

Comment: Dá *sintax error* por causa da identação talvez. Qual o motivo de usar o `else` no `for`?

Comment: Hmm nunca pensei em retirar o else vou ver aqui.

Comment: Sem o else, ele ignora se a variavel ta na range (1, 1).
Fui precipitado, desculpe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele sempre entrará no `else` porque não tem nenhum `break`.

O else para o for funciona da seguinte forma, caso a condição que você quer seja satisfeita, saia com o break, senão ele executará o `else`, considerando que o for não atendeu ao que você esperava.

Em adição, acredito que o `else`, nesse caso, seja desnecessário, já que você só quer repetir uma atribuição uma vez...

O que parece que você quer são ifs e não fors, vou colocar o código que eu imagino que você queira:

```
def filters(a, b, c):
   if a in range(1, 2):
        d = "video"
   else:
        d = ""

   if b in range(1, 2):
        e = "&lclk=short"
   else:
        e = ""

   if c in range(1, 2):
        f = "&lclk=hd"
   else:
        f = ""

   i = ("&filters=%s%s%s" % (e, d, f))
   return i
```

Imagino que seja isso que você quer fazer. Caso você só queira um valor fixo (e não uma lista, como no caso do `range`), substitua pelo seguinte código:

```
def filters(a, b, c):
   if a == 1:
        d = "video"
   else:
        d = ""

   if b == 1:
        e = "&lclk=short"
   else:
        e = ""

   if c == 1:
        f = "&lclk=hd"
   else:
        f = ""

   i = ("&filters=%s%s%s" % (e, d, f))
   return i
```

Comment: Quando eu uso break, ele ignora se a variavel esta na range :/ .

Comment: É porque você quer ifs, não?

Comment: if(a = 1):
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Por algum motivo, ele fala invalid syntax :/

Comment: Oq eu quero é tipo uma configuração, que com parametros certos retorne algo, talvez def não seja o certo pra isso.

Comment: No if, o ideal seria utilizar o `==`. Caso você queira valores fixos, pode substituir os ranges, coloquei achando que você estava só dando um exemplo...

Comment: Nossa, o if x in range() deu certo! Não sabia que dava pra fazer isso :p valeu pela resposta! "digitando e aprendendo" hehe.

Comment: Usando só if, ele ignora o if ou da syntax error se não for " == ".